# Microsoft ODBC v18 is not find by APT

Tags: apt, 22.04, microsoft, odbc

I'm following [these](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu18) instructions to install the ODBC driver v18 on Ubuntu 22.04.
I'm aware that the script does not want to install anything for Ubuntu 22.04 but I bet it's a typo because the repository for [22.04](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/) does exist.

After issuing:

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
```

it does not find version 18:

```
$ apt-cache search msodbc
msodbcsql17 - ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)
```

What is my fault here?

### EDIT

Testing code after answer by `mizera`:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$SERVER = "192.168.0.50";
$DATABASE = "DB";
$DRIVER = "/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-18.so";
const USERNAME = "user";
const PASSWORD = "pswd";

try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:driver=$DRIVER;server=$SERVER;database=$DATABASE", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
    echo "Connection to database failed:" . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage();
    echo '</div>';

    var_dump($e);
}
```

The output is:

```
object(PDOException)#3 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(21) "could not find driver" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(27) "/home/user/www/database.php" ["line":protected]=> int(25) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(27) "/home/user/www/database.php" ["line"]=> int(25) ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct" ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [1]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(25) "/home/user/www/tables.php" ["line"]=> int(2) ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "/home/user/www/database.php" } ["function"]=> string(7) "require" } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["errorInfo"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Thats a question for Microsoft - its possible the version 18 is not yet packaged for 22.04 in their repos

Comment: I made a [discussion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/odbc-drivers-for-ubuntu-22-04/m-p/3356858#M1595) on MS tech community about this subject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried install from Ubuntu 21.10 package, and it is working (first step is important, because without it install cause error):

`apt-get install odbcinst`

`sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

`echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.10/prod impish main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`

`apt update`

`apt install msodbcsql18`

**EDIT:**
My answer was about install driver, if you want to use with PHP, try these steps for PHP 8.1 (php-dev, pecl, php-pear etc):

```
    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
    apt-get update -y
    apt-get install php8.1-dev -y --allow-unauthenticated
    apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y
    apt install php-pear -y 
    pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
    pecl install sqlsrv
    printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
    printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
    phpenmod -v 8.1 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
    systemctl restart apache2
```

**EDIT2**
And code for testing (against MSSql Server 2016):

```
    $conn = \sqlsrv_connect(
        $server, 
            [
                'Database' => $db, 
                'UID' => $user, 
                'PWD' => $pass, 
                'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8', 
                'Encrypt' => 1, 
                'TrustServerCertificate' => 1
            ]
        );
    if ($conn === false) {
        echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
        die(print_r(\sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

Comment: I followed exactly your instruction and I have `/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-18.so` that is a symlink to `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.0.so.1.1`. Setting either one to the code above leads to the "driver not found error" (see question updated). I have to change anything in the code?

Comment: May you share your testing code to understand why it does not work on my system?

Comment: echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jelly main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

For Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to install msodbcsql18 package on a Jammy 22.04 docker container and Google brings here. It seems as of June 2023 the package is already there. lsb-base and apt-key commands fail and you can install it as following:

```
curl -sS https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mssql.gpg
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
```

You most likely need to use sudo or su. This is from CI which already runs as root